# Canonical Tag Confusion

Tags: tags, canonical-link

My mate's website got redesigned and the webdevelopers changed also the URL structure ( I reckon its cos the website is build that way...) and we have pages like that now:
http://optykbrilliant.pl/index.php/aktualnosci

and what really worries me is this bit .../index.php/...which is used across the whole site...

Normally people have it only on the home page and put rel ='canonical' on it and have the duplicate content issues sorted out...Obviously here the content isn't duplicated across the whole website but only on home page when we have these 2 versions:

optykbrilliant.pl/

optykbrilliant.pl/index.php/

but my question is if I place rel canonical on **http://www.optykbrilliant.pl/index.php/** would it affect any other pages which contain http://www.optykbrilliant.pl/index.php/.. and another parameter here (I mean placed after /index.php/....)?

Or it wont affect any other page but will apply only to optykbrilliant.pl/index.php/?

Thanks for your opinion on that.

Answer (score 1):

The canonical tag is definitive, not catch all.  So if you place a canonical on

```
optykbrilliant.pl/index.php/
```

It will only effect that page